# Strange SSRS parameter behavior

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a parameter in SSRS called Team.  The parameter is populated by this SQL:

```
Select Distinct TeamName
From TeamOrganization
Where PersonUnit in (@Units)
Union All
Select 'Unknown'
Order by TeamName
```

When I run this, the Team drop down works fine.  However, when I change the SQL to this:

```
Select Distinct TeamName
From TeamOrganization
Where PersonUnit in (@Units)
  And    PeriodEndDate > @DerivedEndDate
Union All
Select 'Unknown'
Order by TeamName
```

The parameter drop down for Team is grayed out and I can't do anything with it until I press the "Create Report" button.  The Team parameter is after the DerivedEndDate and Units parameters, so that's not what's holding things up.  I've made this change to other reports in the project with no problems.

Comment: Does your **DerivedEndDate** parameter have a default value? If so, does it return results in your second query?

Comment: DerivedEndDate does have a default and the new query returns results.